# Borrar (con erase) un elemento de un vector de struct: no encuentra el miembro delimitador

Tags: c++

la consigna del problema es así:

> Un archivo binario contiene una base de datos de registros de tipo ficha como el
> que se indica en el recuadro generada por un programa C++. Cuando un usuario borra un registro desde
> el programa, marca el registro como borrado colocando true en el campo borrado, pero no lo quita del
> archivo. El archivo es ahora demasiado extenso. Escriba una clase con algún método que acceda al
> archivo y lo ‘limpie’ eliminando definitivamente todos los registros con miembro borrado en true. Use
> la clase en un programa C++.

```
struct ficha {
bool borrado;
string dni, ape, nom;
float h;
}
```

Mi planteo es el siguiente (tuve que modificar el struct para que funcione con archivos binarios):

````
```

    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <vector>
    using namespace std;
    
    struct Ficha {
        bool borrado;
        char dni[50];
        char ape[50];
        char nom[50];
        int size_str = 50;
        float h;
    };
    
    class Ejemplo {
        vector<Ficha>f;
        string nomArch;
    public:
        void Cargar(string nom) {
            nomArch = nom;
            fstream archi(nomArch, ios::binary|ios::ate|ios::out);
            int Tamanio = archi.tellg()/sizeof(Ficha);
            archi.seekg(0);
            Ficha aux;
            for(int i = 0; i < Tamanio; i++) {
                archi.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&aux.borrado), sizeof(aux.borrado));
                archi.read(aux.dni, aux.size_str);
                archi.read(aux.ape, aux.size_str);
                archi.read(aux.nom, aux.size_str);
            }
            f.push_back(aux);
        }
        **
        void Modificar() {
            ofstream arch(nomArch, ios::binary|ios::in|ios::trunc);
            for (auto i = f.begin(); i != f.end(); ++i) {
                if (*i.borrado == true) {
                    f.erase(i);
                }
            }
        }
        **
        void Guardar() {
            ofstream archi(nomArch, ios::binary|ios::in|ios::trunc);
            Ficha aux;
            for(size_t i = 0; i<f.size(); i++) {
                archi.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&aux.borrado), sizeof(aux.borrado));
                archi.write(aux.dni, aux.size_str);
                archi.write(aux.ape, aux.size_str);
                archi.write(aux.nom, aux.size_str);
            }
        }
    };
````

Pero el compilador retorna un error en la función marcada con asteriscos.

El error dice que el vector no tiene un miembro en el struct que se llame borrado.

Cómo podría hacer para que el iterador utilice el campo delimitador del struct (borrado)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si miramos [su documentación](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator), veremos que un [RandomAccessIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator) no tiene el `operator*( )`; de ahí el correcto error que estás recibiendo.

En su lugar, si proporciona el `operator->( )`. Ese es el que tenemos que usar:

```
if( i->borrado == true) {
    f.erase( i );
}
```

Comment: El random acces iterator si tiene el operador *, ya que cumple con los requisitos del  legacy input iterator. La jerarquia se puede ver [aqui](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator). De hecho, se puede ver en el codigo haciendolo asi: `i.operator*().borrado == true` @Trauma